# Contact Form Security

Tags: theme-development, security, contact, sanitization

Building my own contact form in Wordpress. Any there any security steps I need to consider other than the typical email etc validation and maybe a captcha. I am not sending any data to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) to protect yourself from [CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

Even though you're not sending anything to the database, I'd suggest using some of the built in [data validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) functions (there is even a `is_email` function for you to use!) to strip out any HTML from your email.  `esc_html( striptags( $your_email_content ) )`, for instance.

You could also throttle contact form submissions from a single IP to prevent someone from submitting the same thing many times. I don't know of any contact form plugins that do that, but the WordPress comment system show you an error page if you submit too many comments within a certain period of time.

Comment: That's very helpful, but I'm not 100% sure about where exactly to check the nonce. I suppose you put the nonce as usual in a hidden field, but then would I then check it before I sent the email (in the same way it's typically used of checking it before writing to the DB)?

Comment: I believe that this contact for is for unregistered users, so in this case nonces won't work because they are created based on current user.

Comment: aah yes that's the case

Comment: @byronyasgur you check/verify nonces while retrieving post request from form, if nonce is verified you're sending data to DB or anywhere else.

Comment: Just to clarify, nonces work fine for non-logged in users -- they just aren't as secure. Internally the nonce functions do use user ID, but if one isn't used, `wp_get_current_user`, which will return `null` if there isn't a user.  Meaning every person gets the same nonce.  You could improve this, of course, by rolling your own nonce functions that identified different people via a cookie or something.